# Why Does my Computer not have ave the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtimes installed

Tags: visual-c++, xampp, visual-c++-2008

So I'm getting ready to do some work with Laravel Homestead, and was following all the installation instructions, and everything was running smoothly until this came up:
[image: **You do not appear to have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtimes installed**]

And then so I went to the link provided at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582
[image: **Link website image**]

After I downloaded what was required, I then got this message, as seen in the picture below:
[image: Post-download message]
Why is it asking to repair or uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable??....I'm afraid of selecting the wrong option!!

Comment: looks like a bug in installer. fire a bug and wait.

Comment: You can always try the repair, as that will generally correct files that may be missing and/or files that might be corrupted. After the repair is done, I would reboot if there is no prompt to do so.

Comment: @PaulT, I chose the repair option (and it said "successfully repaired"), and then I rebooted, and I still get the same response...this is absolutely crazy!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to reinstall visual c++ or if it doesn't work install a different version of visual c++ and select appropriate version of xampp that runs with it.

I personally downloaded latest version of xampp that runs with visual c ++. 2015 and for days I lost sleep getting dll error. Then I installed visual c ++ 2008 and a lower version of xampp and it worked.

Make sure you select PHP version 5.2 and above for oops. Make sure you select 32 bit (x86) for visual c++ even if u r using 64 bit computer because xampp runs only in visual c++ 32 bit version. Also download service pack 1 from Windows site and update Windows OS using it. I think that will solve the problem.